# retrieving data from JObject

Tags: json.net

I have an JObject like this one:

```
{
  "111": {
    "Group": 1,
    "Category": 1
  },
  "005": {
    "Group": 1,
    "Category": 1
  }
}
    base {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer}: {
  "111": {
    "Group": 1,
    "Category": 1
  },
  "005": {
    "Group": 1,
    "Category": 1
  }
}
```

I need to enumerate, for each properties of first level object (for example for "111"), their properties list.
For example, write out:
111: Group, Category
005: Group, Category

I found, for the first level properties, something like this:

```
List<string> keys = myJO.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

but for the nested properties?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Try this:

```
string json = @"
{
  ""111"": {
    ""Group"": 1,
    ""Category"": 1
  },
  ""005"": {
    ""Group"": 1,
    ""Category"": 1
  }
}";

JObject myJO = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (JProperty prop in myJO.Properties())
{
    JObject childJO = (JObject)prop.Value;
    List<string> keys = childJO.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + string.Join(", ", keys));
}
```

Output:

```
111: Group, Category
005: Group, Category
```